# Add selector to URL

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using TTTAttributedLabel to add links to parts of the label.
I would like the link to invoke a selector (method in the same file), instead of a web URL.

Is it possible, and how ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was add behaviour in the `delegate` method of `TTTAttributedLabel` : `didSelectLink`... methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can create links with your own url scheme like `<a href="myScheme://mySelector1"` and on `UIWebView` delegate just catch this redirect

```
NSString * const kMyURLScheme = @"myScheme";  
NSString * const kMySelector = @"mySelector1";


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navi
gationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

 if ([[request.URL scheme] isEqualToString:kMyURLScheme]) {

     SEL mySel = NSSelectorFromString([URL host]); // Do something with @selector


     return NO; // remember to return NO to denie `UIWebView` execute your request
 }
```

Comment: OK. I'm not well versed with URL schemes.
So, should I set @"@selector(myMethod)" to kMyURLScheme, and @"myMethod" to kMySelector ??

Comment: no, just put link to press on like <a href="myScheme://mySelector" and just put breakpoint on UIWebView delegate to see it

Answer (score 0):

I have used `UILabel` instead of TTTAttributedLabel. This code might work with it also:

```
[label addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[label setText:@"hello world i love iphone"];

 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

CGRect rect = label.frame;
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height);
CGRect newRect2 = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x+rect.size.width/2, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(newRect, touchPoint)) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(printMessage:) withObject:@"First half of label touched"];
}
else if (CGRectContainsPoint(newRect2, touchPoint)) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(printMessage:) withObject:@"Second half of label touched"];
}
}

-(void) printMessage:(NSString *)message
{
NSLog(@"%@",message);
}
```